# .NET client to java service using message and transport certificates

Tags: c#, .net, wse

I am trying to make a .NET client using WSE 3.0 custom policy. I have local wsdl because service uses https with certificate protection. Request soap message needs to be signed and encrypted with certificates one from client for signing, and one from service provider for encryption. I used custom security assertions found on MSDN, here is how my class looks like:

```
 namespace RegistryProxy
 {
    class CustomSecurityAssertion : SecurityPolicyAssertion
    {
    TokenProvider<X509SecurityToken> serviceX509TokenProviderValue;
    TokenProvider<X509SecurityToken> clientX509TokenProviderValue;

    public TokenProvider<X509SecurityToken> ClientX509TokenProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return clientX509TokenProviderValue;
        }
        set
        {
            clientX509TokenProviderValue = value;
        }
    }

    public TokenProvider<X509SecurityToken> ServiceX509TokenProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return serviceX509TokenProviderValue;
        }
        set
        {
            serviceX509TokenProviderValue = value;
        }
    }


    public CustomSecurityAssertion()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override SoapFilter CreateClientOutputFilter(FilterCreationContext context)
    {
        return new CustomSecurityClientOutputFilter(this);
    }

    public override SoapFilter CreateClientInputFilter(FilterCreationContext context)
    {
        return new CustomSecurityClientInputFilter(this);
    }

    public override SoapFilter CreateServiceInputFilter(FilterCreationContext context)
    {
        return new CustomSecurityServerInputFilter(this);
    }

    public override SoapFilter CreateServiceOutputFilter(FilterCreationContext context)
    {
        return new CustomSecurityServerOutputFilter(this);
    }


    public override void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader, IDictionary<string, Type> extensions)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        if (extensions == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("extensions");

        bool isEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        base.ReadAttributes(reader);
        reader.ReadStartElement("CustomSecurityAssertion");

        if (!isEmpty)
        {
            if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "clientToken")
            {
                reader.ReadStartElement();
                reader.MoveToContent();
                // Get the registed security token provider for X.509 certificate security credentials. 
                Type type = extensions[reader.Name];
                object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                if (instance == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Unable to instantiate policy extension of type {0}.", type.AssemblyQualifiedName));

                TokenProvider<X509SecurityToken> clientProvider = instance as TokenProvider<X509SecurityToken>;

                // Read the child elements that provide the details about the client's X.509 certificate. 
                clientProvider.ReadXml(reader, extensions);
                this.ClientX509TokenProvider = clientProvider;
                reader.ReadEndElement();
            }
            if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "serviceToken")
            {
                reader.ReadStartElement();
                reader.MoveToContent();

                // Get the registed security token provider for X.509 certificate security credentials. 
                Type type = extensions[reader.Name];
                object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                if (instance == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Unable to instantiate policy extension of type {0}.", type.AssemblyQualifiedName));

                TokenProvider<X509SecurityToken> serviceProvider = instance as TokenProvider<X509SecurityToken>;
                // Read the child elements that provide the details about the Web service's X.509 certificate.
                serviceProvider.ReadXml(reader, extensions);
                this.ServiceX509TokenProvider = serviceProvider;
                reader.ReadEndElement();
            }
            base.ReadElements(reader, extensions);
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }
    public override IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> GetExtensions()
    {
        // Add the CustomSecurityAssertion custom policy assertion to the list of registered
        // policy extensions.
        List<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> extensions = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Type>>();
        extensions.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Type>("CustomSecurityAssertion", this.GetType()));
        if (serviceX509TokenProviderValue != null)
        {
            // Add any policy extensions that read child elements of the <serviceToken> element
            // to the list of registered policy extensions.
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> innerExtensions = serviceX509TokenProviderValue.GetExtensions();
            if (innerExtensions != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> extension in innerExtensions)
                {
                    extensions.Add(extension);
                }
            }
        }
        if (clientX509TokenProviderValue != null)
        {
            // Add any policy extensions that read child elements of the <clientToken> element
            // to the list of registered policy extensions.
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> innerExtensions = clientX509TokenProviderValue.GetExtensions();
            if (innerExtensions != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> extension in innerExtensions)
                {
                    extensions.Add(extension);
                }
            }
        }
        return extensions;
    }
    // </snippet16

}

class RequestState
{
    SecurityToken clientToken;
    SecurityToken serverToken;


    public RequestState(SecurityToken cToken, SecurityToken sToken)
    {
        clientToken = cToken;
        serverToken = sToken;         
    }

    public SecurityToken ClientToken
    {
        get { return clientToken; }
    }

    public SecurityToken ServerToken
    {
        get { return serverToken; }
    }
}
class CustomSecurityServerInputFilter : ReceiveSecurityFilter
{
    public CustomSecurityServerInputFilter(CustomSecurityAssertion parentAssertion)
        : base(parentAssertion.ServiceActor, false)
    {

    }
    public override void ValidateMessageSecurity(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
    {
        SecurityToken clientToken = null;
        SecurityToken serverToken = null;

        // Ensure incoming SOAP messages are signed and encrypted.
        foreach (ISecurityElement elem in security.Elements)
        {
            if (elem is MessageSignature)
            {
                MessageSignature sig = (MessageSignature)elem;
                clientToken = sig.SigningToken;
            }

            if (elem is EncryptedData)
            {
                EncryptedData enc = (EncryptedData)elem;
                serverToken = enc.SecurityToken;
            }
        }

        if (clientToken == null || serverToken == null)
            throw new Exception("Incoming message did not meet security requirements");

        RequestState state = new RequestState(clientToken, serverToken);

        envelope.Context.OperationState.Set(state);
    }
}

class CustomSecurityServerOutputFilter : SendSecurityFilter
{

    public CustomSecurityServerOutputFilter(CustomSecurityAssertion parentAssertion)
        : base(parentAssertion.ServiceActor, false)
    {
    }

    public override void SecureMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
    {
        RequestState state = envelope.Context.OperationState.Get<RequestState>();

        // Sign the message with the Web service's security token.
        security.Tokens.Add(state.ServerToken);
        security.Elements.Add(new MessageSignature(state.ServerToken));

        // Encrypt the message with the client's security token.
        security.Elements.Add(new EncryptedData(state.ClientToken));
    }
}
class CustomSecurityClientInputFilter : ReceiveSecurityFilter
{
    public CustomSecurityClientInputFilter(CustomSecurityAssertion parentAssertion)
        : base(parentAssertion.ServiceActor, true)
    {

    }

    public override void ValidateMessageSecurity(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
    {
        RequestState state;
        bool signed = false;
        bool encrypted = false;

        // Get the request state out of the operation state.
        state = envelope.Context.OperationState.Get<RequestState>();

        // Make sure the message was signed with the server's security token.
        foreach (ISecurityElement elem in security.Elements)
        {
            if (elem is MessageSignature)
            {
                MessageSignature sig = (MessageSignature)elem;

                if (sig.SigningToken.Equals(state.ServerToken))
                    signed = true;
            }

            if (elem is EncryptedData)
            {
                EncryptedData enc = (EncryptedData)elem;

                if (enc.SecurityToken.Equals(state.ClientToken))
                    encrypted = true;
            }
        }

        if (!signed || !encrypted)
            throw new Exception("Response message does not meet security requirements");
    }
}
class CustomSecurityClientOutputFilter : SendSecurityFilter
{
    SecurityToken clientToken;
    SecurityToken serverToken;

    public CustomSecurityClientOutputFilter(CustomSecurityAssertion parentAssertion)
        : base(parentAssertion.ServiceActor, true)
    {
        ISecurityTokenManager stm = SecurityTokenManager.GetSecurityTokenManagerByTokenType(WSTrust.TokenTypes.X509v3);
        X509SecurityTokenManager x509tm = stm as X509SecurityTokenManager;

        x509tm.DefaultSessionKeyAlgorithm = "AES128";
        x509tm.DefaultKeyAlgorithm = "RSA15";


        // Get the client security token.
        clientToken = X509TokenProvider.CreateToken(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, "serial removed", X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber);

        // Get the server security token.
        serverToken = X509TokenProvider.CreateToken(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, "serial removed",X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber);

    }

    public override void SecureMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
    {

        ISecurityTokenManager stm = X509SecurityTokenManager.GetSecurityTokenManagerByTokenType(WSTrust.TokenTypes.X509v3);
        X509SecurityTokenManager x509tm = stm as X509SecurityTokenManager;

        x509tm.DefaultSessionKeyAlgorithm = "AES128";
        x509tm.DefaultKeyAlgorithm = "RSA15";

        // Sign the SOAP message with the client's security token.
        security.Tokens.Add(clientToken);
        security.Elements.Add(new MessageSignature(clientToken));

        // Encrypt the SOAP message with the client's security token.
        security.Elements.Add(new EncryptedData(serverToken));

        // Encrypt the client's security token with the server's security token.
        security.Elements.Add(new EncryptedData(serverToken, "#" + clientToken.Id));

        // Store the client and server security tokens in the request state.
        RequestState state = new RequestState(clientToken, serverToken);

        // Store the request state in the proxy's operation state. 
        // This makes these tokens accessible when SOAP responses are 
        // verified to have sufficient security requirements.
        envelope.Context.OperationState.Set(state);
    }
  }
}
```

After class in set into project I made a wse3policyCache.config to use certificates:

```
<policies xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wse/2005/06/policy">
  <extensions>
    <extension name="CustomSecurityAssertion" type="GiftRegistryProxy.CustomSecurityAssertion,GiftRegistryProxy" />
  </extensions>
  <policy name="ClientPolicy">
    <CustomSecurityAssertion>
      <clientToken>
        <x509
          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="My"
          findValue="serial number"
          findType="FindBySerialNumber" />
      </clientToken>
      <serviceToken>
        <x509
          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="My"
          findValue="serial number"
          findType="FindBySerialNumber" />
      </serviceToken>      
    </CustomSecurityAssertion>
  </policy>  
</policies>
```

And when everything is set I run my client, my client returns message:

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

**When I look Network monitor it says**

```
TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello.

TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Server Hello. Certificate. Certificate.

TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Certificate. Client Key Exchange.; TLS Rec Layer-2 Cipher Change Spec; TLS Rec Layer-3 HandShake: Encrypted Handshake Message.

TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 Encrypted Alert --Problem
```

Can anyone explain me why this happens and type here if possible?

Comment: Please, don't put your *whole* project in here. Try to locate only the relevant parts

Comment: Sorry, I put some modifications to CustomSecurityAssertion Class so I thought it could be important.